# implement circuit breaker with openfeign in spring-boot 2.4 and spring cloud 2020

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hystrix, openfeign, spring-cloud-circuitbreaker

If I want to  upgrade to spring-boot 2.4 and spring cloud 2020.

Now that spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix has been removed from spring-cloud-netflix,
How can I implement circuit breaker with openfeign?

I did a direct import but my IDE cannot resolve feign.hystrix.enabled and feign is not executing the fallback class.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```